# Upload file using pre-signed URL PUT method not working Python requests

Tags: python, amazon-s3, python-requests, boto3, put

I'm trying to read file residing inside an s3 bucket and upload it to another s3 bucket through pre-signed url. I have tried to upload single file, that works fine. But if I try to upload list of files in a bucket, data can't be uploaded. It's always giving the response code as 200, but data is uploaded in the target s3 location especially with large files.

My python code is given below.

```
import boto3
import requests
from io import BytesIO
 for file in file_list:#list of file names in the bucket
    pre_url=getPreSinedUrl()#for each file method will return a separate pre-signed url to upload file
    data_in_bytes = s3.get_object(Bucket="my-bucket", Key=file)['Body'].read()
    res = requests.put(pre_url, data=BytesIO(data_in_bytes), headers=my_header)
    print(res.status_code)
```

Any help why the file in s3 is not getting uploaded?

Comment: What do you mean by "single file" and "different files"? What is so "different" about those "different files" from the "single file?

Comment: means, tried with one file, its working and when try list of files in a bucket, not getting uploaded